# How to run a serial mediation with multilevel data in r?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I need to run a serial mediation with multilevel data. The path is as follows:

Agreeableness (continous, level 2, independant variable) -> response to a question (continous, level 1, mediator) -> amount of positive feedback given (continous, level 1, mediator) -> positive affect (continous, level 1, outcome).

This will likely have to be a fixed effect rather than random effect model due to limited data (n= ~350).

How would I do this in r?

Thanks in advance!

I've looked online but examples don't specify whether the mediators are level 1 or level 2 and whether a serial mediation with the path I've specified